# Threaded wire connections

Tags: connector, wire, thread

I'm working on a senior design project that is using three 20-30 gauge wires that are going into a *detachable* box.

The idea is that the box has three wires coming out of it, and the three wires that need to go into it are going to get connected to the three wires coming out of the box.

What I am looking for is 3 male and female wire connectors that are threaded to allow some sort of water resistance. Does anyone know of a good idea or plan here? I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks

Edit: Here is a picture, the wires on the left are going into my system. 
[image: I need a connection between the wires]

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a single cable?

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph appears to say that the three wires coming out of the box go back into the box?!?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The box has a total of how many wires? Does "20-30 gauge wires" mean that you have a variety of wire gauges or that you in fact have 20 individual 30AWG wires? Then you state three wires going out and then three wires going in, is that a total of three or six wires? Please reword your question and include some more detail so we can better understand your request.

Comment: It isn't worded great, but makes sense to me. OP is saying that they have 3 wires, which could be 20 to 30 AWG (they haven't chosen, with 30 being the smallest for the current needed and 20 the largest for mechanical reasons I assume). The box is detachable, so you have 3 wires coming out of the box. The 3 wires going in is referring to the cables coming from the other device. So basically OP wants a water resistant disconnect for 3 wires of anywhere from 20 to 30 AWG.

Comment: Actually OP could have meant that the 3 wires are different sizes between 20 and 30 AWG, so we do need more info.

Comment: That makes more sense. But how water resistant? If it's as simple as rain then anything rated ip65 and up.

Comment: I. Wolfe's first guess was right. I'm sorry I wanted to add a picture but was on the go

Three same sized wires come out of a T-Shirt, and are going to connect to Three Same Sized Wires going INTO a box, I need a connection between the two wires, three times.

Comment: If the connections are inside "the box" (the circle above?), is it sufficient for the box to be watertight?  Will you need to get back into the box frequently?  Maybe just some RTV Silicone?